# How to create a new column by iterating a mathematical formula over rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration, formula, rows

I have a dataframe df with several rows:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df
          date        time        data
0   15.01.2012    13:58:00    0.000212
1   15.01.2012    13:58:03    0.052521
2   15.01.2012    13:58:06    0.000373
..
```

I would like to have a new column df['seconds'] where I can transform my time value( df['time'] in seconds value. The difference between each value is 3 seconds so I would like to create an iteration which will give me a new row by adding 3 to the previous one.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dataframe is sorted by `time`, and the difference between subsequent rows is always 3 seconds, you can simply assign a linear range as the new column:

```py
import numpy as np

df['seconds'] = np.arange(start=0, stop=3 * len(df), step=3)
```